# Rewriting imperative for loop to declarative style in Scala

Tags: scala, loops, functional-programming, tail-recursion, declarative

How do I rewrite the following loop (pattern) into Scala, either using built-in higher order functions or tail recursion?

This the example of an iteration pattern where you do a computation (comparison, for example) of two list elements, but only if the second one comes after first one in the original input. Note that the +1 step is used here, but in general, it could be +n.

```
public List<U> mapNext(List<T> list) {
    List<U> results = new ArrayList();

    for (i = 0; i < list.size - 1; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < list.size; j++) {
            results.add(doSomething(list[i], list[j]))
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

So far, I've come up with this in Scala:

```
def mapNext[T, U](list: List[T])(f: (T, T) => U): List[U] = {
  @scala.annotation.tailrec
  def loop(ix: List[T], jx: List[T], res: List[U]): List[U] = (ix, jx) match {
    case (_ :: _ :: is, Nil) => loop(ix, ix.tail, res)
    case (i :: _ :: is, j :: Nil) => loop(ix.tail, Nil, f(i, j) :: res)
    case (i :: _ :: is, j :: js) => loop(ix, js, f(i, j) :: res)
    case _ => res
  }

  loop(list, Nil, Nil).reverse
}
```

Edit:
To all contributors, I only wish I could accept every answer as solution :)

Comment: And so? What's the issue?

Comment: It looks somewhat clunky, a bit off, and I was wondering if there's a better, more concise way.

Comment: Using provided `.map` or `.foldLeft`, improving the pattern matching (but that depends on the cases you're the better to understand)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comeback Attempt:

After deleting my first attempt to give an answer I put some more thought into it and came up with another, at least shorter solution.

```
def mapNext[T, U](list: List[T])(f: (T, T) => U): List[U] = {
  @tailrec
  def loop(in: List[T], out: List[U]): List[U] = in match {
    case Nil          => out
    case head :: tail => loop(tail, out ::: tail.map { f(head, _) } )
  }

  loop(list, Nil)
}
```

I would also like to recommend the enrich my library pattern for adding the mapNext function to the List api (or with some adjustments to any other collection).

```
object collection {
  object Implicits {
    implicit class RichList[A](private val underlying: List[A]) extends AnyVal {
      def mapNext[U](f: (A, A) => U): List[U] = {
        @tailrec
        def loop(in: List[A], out: List[U]): List[U] = in match {
          case Nil          => out
          case head :: tail => loop(tail, out ::: tail.map { f(head, _) } )
        }

        loop(underlying, Nil)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can use the function like:

```
list.mapNext(doSomething)
```

Again, there is a downside, as concatenating lists is relatively expensive.
However, variable assignemends inside for comprehensions can be quite inefficient, too (as this improvement task for dotty [Scala Wart: Convoluted de-sugaring of for-comprehensions](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/2573) suggests).

**UPDATE**

Now that I'm into this, I simply cannot let go :(

Concerning 'Note that the +1 step is used here, but in general, it could be +n.'

I extended my proposal with some parameters to cover more situations:

```
object collection {
  object Implicits {
    implicit class RichList[A](private val underlying: List[A]) extends AnyVal {
      def mapNext[U](f: (A, A) => U): List[U] = {
        @tailrec
        def loop(in: List[A], out: List[U]): List[U] = in match {
          case Nil          => out
          case head :: tail => loop(tail, out ::: tail.map { f(head, _) } )
        }

        loop(underlying, Nil)
      }

      def mapEvery[U](step: Int)(f: A => U) = {
        @tailrec
        def loop(in: List[A], out: List[U]): List[U] = {
          in match {
            case Nil => out.reverse
            case head :: tail => loop(tail.drop(step), f(head) :: out)
          }
        }

        loop(underlying, Nil)
      }
      def mapDrop[U](drop1: Int, drop2: Int, step: Int)(f: (A, A) => U): List[U] = {
        @tailrec
        def loop(in: List[A], out: List[U]): List[U] = in match {
          case Nil          => out
          case head :: tail =>
            loop(tail.drop(drop1), out ::: tail.drop(drop2).mapEvery(step) { f(head, _) } )
        }

        loop(underlying, Nil)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This isn't the same iteration pattern as demonstrated in the OP's question.

Comment: undeleted and (hopefully) improved

Answer (score 2):

Here's my stab. I think it's pretty readable. The intuition is: for each head of the list, apply the function to the head and every other member of the tail. Then recurse on the tail of the list.

```
def mapNext[U, T](list: List[U], fun: (U, U) => T): List[T] = list match {
  case Nil => Nil
  case (first :: Nil) => Nil
  case (first :: rest) => rest.map(fun(first, _: U)) ++ mapNext(rest, fun)
}
```

Here's a sample run

```
scala> mapNext(List(1, 2, 3, 4), (x: Int, y: Int) => x + y)
res6: List[Int] = List(3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7)
```

This one isn't explicitly tail recursive but an accumulator could be easily added to make it.

Answer (score 2):

Recursion is certainly an option, but the standard library offers some alternatives that will achieve the same iteration pattern.

Here's a very simple setup for demonstration purposes.

```
val lst = List("a","b","c","d")
def doSomething(a:String, b:String) = a+b
```

And here's one way to get at what we're after.

```
val resA = lst.tails.toList.init.flatMap(tl=>tl.tail.map(doSomething(tl.head,_)))
// resA: List[String] = List(ab, ac, ad, bc, bd, cd)
```

This works but the fact that there's a `map()` within a `flatMap()` suggests that a `for` comprehension might be used to pretty it up.

```
val resB = for {
  tl <- lst.tails
  if tl.nonEmpty
  h = tl.head
  x <- tl.tail
} yield doSomething(h, x)  // resB: Iterator[String] = non-empty iterator

resB.toList  // List(ab, ac, ad, bc, bd, cd)
```

In both cases the `toList` cast is used to get us back to the original collection type, which might not actually be necessary depending on what further processing of the collection is required.

Answer (score 1):

```
list       // [a, b, c, d, ...]
  .indices // [0, 1, 2, 3, ...]
  .flatMap { i =>
    elem = list(i) // Don't redo access every iteration of the below map.
    list.drop(i + 1) // Take only the inputs that come after the one we're working on
      .map(doSomething(elem, _))
  }
// Or with a monad-comprehension
for {
  index <- list.indices
  thisElem = list(index)
  thatElem <- list.drop(index + 1)
} yield doSomething(thisElem, thatElem)
```

You start, not with the list, but with its `indices`. Then, you use `flatMap`, because each index goes to a list of elements. Use `drop` to take only the elements after the element we're working on, and map that list to actually run the computation. Note that this has terrible time complexity, because most operations here, `indices`/`length`, `flatMap`, `map`, are `O(n)` in the list size, and `drop` and `apply` are `O(n)` in the argument.

You can get better performance if you a) stop using a linked list (`List` is good for LIFO, sequential access, but `Vector` is better in the general case), and b) make this a tiny bit uglier

```
val len = vector.length
(0 until len)
  .flatMap { thisIdx =>
    val thisElem = vector(thisIdx)
    ((thisIdx + 1) until len)
      .map { thatIdx =>
        doSomething(thisElem, vector(thatIdx))
      }
  }
// Or
val len = vector.length
for {
  thisIdx <- 0 until len
  thisElem = vector(thisIdx)
  thatIdx <- (thisIdx + 1) until len
  thatElem = vector(thatIdx)
} yield doSomething(thisElem, thatElem)
```

If you really need to, you can generalize either version of this code to all `IndexedSeq`s, by using some `implicit` `CanBuildFrom` parameters, but I won't cover that.